# Combining getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to combine getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName to narrow a search down and count the resulting nodes, but the second search always results in a length of 0, and I've no idea why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Stuff</p>
  <p class="content">Stuff2</p>
  <p>Stuff</p>
  <p class="content">Stuff2</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   pElements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   console.log(pElements);
   for(i = 0; i < pElements.length; i++) {
    console.log(pElements[i].getElementsByClassName("content").length);
   }
   //console.log(document.querySelectorAll('p.content').length);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I know I can use querySelectorAll for this like the line I have commented out, but I'd like to understand why the first solution isn't working, and what I can do to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the first example is that:

```
pElements[i].getElementsByClassName("content")
```

searches for children of the p element. But since it is actually on the same element, they are not found.

W3C [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp):
"The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of an element's child elements with the specified class name"

EDIT: To find if a p element has the content class, instead of getElementsByClassName(), you could use

```
pElements[i].classList.contains("content")
```

which will return true if the element has the class. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

EDIT2: A more backwards-compatible way would be to get the `className` property, split it on spaces and iterate the array to see if the class is there.

```
var names = pElements[i].className.split(" ");
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  if(names[i] === "content"){
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(found){
 //Your code here
}
```

Comment: So it's not really possible to combine the two (ByTagName & ByClassName) if you're looking for elements that have both the right tag and class?

Comment: Added a more backwards-compatible way too.

Answer (score 2):

You can NOT combine `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName`. Because as mentioned by @juunas, `pElements` now consists of the result consisting of an array of all the `<p>` elements.

And when you apply the `getElementsByClassName` to this result-set, using `pElements[i].getElementsByClassName("content")`, it searches in the child elements of `pElements`.

**Suggestive Result** :
Use the `getAttribute()` function to check the `class` of each element in `pElements`, like,

```
pElements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
console.log(pElements);
for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < pElements.length; i++) {
    if (pElements[i].getAttribute("class") === "content") {
        j++;
    }
}
console.log("Length of the resulting nodes: ", j);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your p-elements dont have any elements with the class "content". The p-elements itself have this class, so you cant find it and 0 is correct.

Change

```
<p class="content">Stuff2</p>
```

To

```
<p><span class="content">Stuff2</span></p>
```

And you will get 1 as the result.